# How to convert a RS-274D gerber to RS-274X

Tags: kicad, gerber, gerbv

I got from a website some gerber files, I tried to have them printed, but they told me that the format is not supported and I need to convert to RS-274X.

I've tried using [gerbv](http://gerbv.geda-project.org/) to open the gerbers and export to the 274x format, but after opening it still complains about some being 274d.

So I've tried a commercial application ([gerbview](https://www.gerbview.com/)), but which managed to convert them but totally screwed up the scaling and ended up with a 1mm wide PCB.

On last resort, I've manually edited the files with a text editor and manually changed the scale of every piece and I've to say KiCAD renders it correctly, but any other viewer (gerbv and the one used by the pcb printing website) does not and still show the scaled down layout.

**EDIT:** as suggested, [here](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/GerberFiles.zip) is the link to the origianl files I want to convert

Comment: If you'd like someone to answer a question about the files, you may want to post a link to the files.

Comment: you're right, I've added it

Comment: They open OK for me in gerbv. Board is about 3" x 4"? I don't see an outline. ELM327 measures 0.1" pitch on the pins.

Comment: @PhilG when I open them they show fine (expect for a mere warning that tells me it's rs274d format) the problem is that they are not acceppted by the pcb manifacturer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain that the issue from the manufacturer is one of file version.  That said, you can open the gerber files in KiCad's gerbview and export to pcbnew.

[image: Export Layers]

From there, you can plot the files as 274X.

[image: PCBNew Plotting]

This doesn't get the drill hits but those are in Excellon format and shouldn't change.